# Customizing presentmodalviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5

Is there is a way to customize presentmodalviewcontroller for iPhone app?

For example:

setting.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentModalViewController:setting animated:YES];

I'd like to use custom modalTransitionStyle, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Using stock UIKit, it is not possible to customize the transition of a presented modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think customization of modalTransitionStyle is allowed in iOS. You can use available transition style by typing UIModalTransitionStyle and a list of available types will be appear. You can choose as per your requirement.